# push object to array and eventually convert array to json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

I am creating an object and pushing it into array.Then I convert it into json.When I alert dataCharts it is returned as:

```
[{"AllLinks":"Link9","LinkURL":"url1"},{"AllLinks":"Link6","LinkURL":"url2"}]
```

Whereas I want it as:

```
[{AllLinks:"Link9",LinkURL:"url1"},{AllLinks:"Link6",LinkURL:"url2"}]
```

My code is as follows:

```
  $.ajax({

    url:  url,

    type: "get",

    headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},

    success: function (data) {

        var array = new Array();

        var temp = new Object();

        for (var i=0; i< data.d.results.length; i++) {

            var it=data.d.results[i];

            array.push({

                "AllLinks": it.AllLinks,  

                "LinkURL": it.LinkURL.Url

            });

        }

        dataCharts=JSON.stringify(array);     

        alert(dataCharts);

        AddDefaultLinks(dataCharts);

    },

    error: function (data) {

        alert(data.responseJSON.error);

    }

});
```

Comment: Your result equals the wanted one??

Comment: Quotes are required in JSON. What you want is not JSON, you will can't have it with `JSON.stringify`. Stringify it manually if you really want your custom format.

Comment: No, my result is first one and i want second one as my answer.

Comment: @dfsq How do i eliminate double quotes around All Links in my result set?

Comment: Not possible with JSON.stringify. But more importantly why you want this. Well anyway, you are doing something wrong, I already see that you pass string here `AddDefaultLinks(dataCharts)` which doesn't make sense.

Comment: In JSON, both key and value pairs must have quotes. You could use regex with the replace() to remove the quotes.

Answer (score -1):

Hint:

```
[{"_aaaa_":"bbbb","_cccc_":"eeee"}]
[{aaaa:"bbbb",cccc:"eeee"}]
```

If you want to remove the quotes: name your label like this:

```
_AllLinks_: it.AllLinks,  

_LinkURL_: it.LinkURL.Url
```

and then remove the underscores and the quotes like this:

```
dataCharts.replace(/"_|_"/g,"")
```

But be carefull that this does not conflict with other data (or take two _ or so)

Comment: @baao: yes. it is.

Comment: @halfbit Thanks !

Comment: @reactjs: so, how about accepting the answer ... the minus from baao hurts me.

Comment: @reactjs: it looks like, you did not accept it until now :)